# Importxml google spreadsheet function

Tags: xml, xpath, google-sheets

I'm trying to import nodes from a xml hosted in my server but I'm getting error:
`=importxml("http://www.jaguatiricadigital.com/notas_xml/NFe33150117082461000153550020000001001857920160.xml";"//*[@id="webkit-xml-viewer-source-xml"]/nfeProc/NFe/infNFe/ide/natOp")`

Though, when I use only a slash as the XPATH query, it returns que whole xml without nodes markups:
`=importxml("http://www.jaguatiricadigital.com/notas_xml/NFe33150117082461000153550020000001001857920160.xml";"/")`

I need to import the nodes as headers and content as rows. 
The XPATH was copied from Chrome. I have already changed double to single quotes as suggested in another topic. 
I know that Excel does this very quickly but I use Mac and the office version doesn't support xml import.

What is possibly wrong ? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your XML has default namespace that you need to consider when creating the XPath. I'm not sure if Google Spreadsheet provide a way to define namespace prefix for use in `IMPORTXML` XPath. If you can't find one, then you can ignore namespaces completely by using `local-name()`. For example, the following XPath will return all elements named `natOp`, ignoring the element's namespace, anywhere in the XML document :

```
//*[local-name()='natOp']
```

Quick test :

[image]

Comment: Great. The namespace was really the problem. Many thanks.